# Spring webflow, spring state machine and HTML5

Tags: html, spring-webflow, state-machine-workflow

Read in this post about spring webflow and spring state machine
https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/ajax-spring-web-flow-and-spring-state-machine/

For my application, I need to maintain state, need to go back and forth between the states. What technologies would you recommend for UI display? Thanks

How can I use HTML 5 as the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any technology compatible with Spring Flow, jsp, jsf, angularJS but if you are specifically interested HTML5 I suggest you to look for Thymeleaf....

Spring Web Flow or the ideas in the blog does not restrict you in anyway for a rendering technology....